# Bitmap and hBitmap memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I capture images from my web camera to Image control in WPF with `WebCam_Capture.dll`. For every captured frame i have event called `webCam_imageCaptured`. It calls every time when i receive new image from web camera. In this event I call method `LoadBitmap` to get hBitmap and receive BitmapSource to put this captured picture to the Image control.
Here is code of this method:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr handle);
public BitmapSource bs;
public IntPtr ip;
public BitmapSource LoadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
   ip = source.GetHbitmap();
   bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
   DeleteObject(ip);
   return bs;
}
```

And here is the code of the event:

```
private void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
{
    //_frameImage is Image WPF control.
     _frameImage.Source = LoadBitmap((System.Drawing.Bitmap)e.WebCamImage);   
}
```

And I have a leak here! RAM loads up to 1 GB and sometimes more! `DeleteObject(ip)` works not every time when it called. When RAM is 1 GB or more, it releases or show me Out of memory error. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you disposing the bitmap when it's no longer needed?

Comment: I've tried to dispose after DeleteObject method. Like this:
source.Dispose(); but it not helped.

Comment: Are you certain that the leak is actually here?  How did you determine that?  Did you use any sort of profiler?  Is it possible that there are references to these BitmapSource objects which are stale?  Why aren't you disposing of your Bitmap after using it?  That is a (temporary) memory leak for sure. Create the BitmapSource using BitmapCacheOptions.OnLoad and get rid of the Bitmap.

Comment: @ED S. Can you show an exapmle?

Comment: Added a response. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the aid of a profiler or even seeing the rest of your code, I can almost guarantee that the "leak" is here:

```
_frameImage.Source = LoadBitmap((System.Drawing.Bitmap)e.WebCamImage);
```

That method is certainly being called very quickly and you are not `Dispose()`ing of your `Bitmaps`.  The GC won't have time to come clean up after you and call the finalizer on each `Bitmap`, so you run out of memory.

You need to call `Dispose()` on that `Bitmap` after you're done with it. The `BitmapSource` makes a copy of the image data anyway, so it shouldn't be needed.  I would try this:

```
private void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
{
    using( Bitmap b = e.WebCamImage )
    {
         _frameImage.Source = LoadBitmap((System.Drawing.Bitmap)e.WebCamImage);   
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that disposing of the bitmap inside this event handler is a valid thing to do (i.e., does anyone else handle this event?)  You may want to expose a `BitmapSource` in the `WebCamEventArgs` class instead so that you can make sure no other clients are relying on that `Bitmap` remaining valid.

That is of course if you wrote the API to being with.  If not you could write a wrapper to make sure your code never actually sees a `Bitmap` and deals only with WPF image types.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This library has leak inside. And it appears in this event. Thank you.